# Check If bootstrap last column is even or odd

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap column in while loop, what I want is if bootstrap last column is  odd then I want column to be 12 (col-12), I found the way to check number even or odd but want to check last number so if last number (last column) is odd I want column to be 12 else remain col-6
I have tried:

```
<div class"<?php echo ($i == (2 || 4 || 6) )?'col-md-6':'col-md-12'; ?>">
       display content there in while loop
</div>

<div class"<?php echo ($i % 2 == 0)?'col-md-6':'col-md-12'; ?>">
   display content there in while loop
</div>
```

but could get the job done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution By m_hutley

Where $i = counter;
$total = acf repeater count;

```
<div class="<?php echo ($i == $total && $total % 2 !== 0 )?'col-md-12':'col-md-6'; ?>" id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <h1><?php echo "contain"; ?></h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You make a mistake in writing HTML. But version with modulo must work:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) { ?>
    <div class="<?php echo ($i%2 === 0) ? 'col-md-6' : 'col-md-12'; ?>">
        display content there in while loop
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: may be, Im not able to explain my need properly, bootstrap column is in while loop out will as follow:

`1.<div class="col-md-6"> content here</div>  2.<div class="col-md-6"> content here</div>
3.<div class="col-md-6"> content here</div>  4.<div class="col-md-6"> content here</div> 
5.<div class="col-md-6"> content here</div> `

As Now you can see last div is equal to 5 which is odd so if last div is odd then i want out to be <div class="col-md-12"> content here </div>